# PowerShell Get-ChildItem - Path Too Long

Tags: powershell, path

I have been stuck with trying to format my output table for a `Get-ChildItem` command.

I have created a script to scan a directory defined in `$Source` to search for files defined by `$Months` and `$Size`. This works fine but some of the directories are longer than 248 characters long and I get file path too long error.

So I want to not include the `$Source` path when it is output to the directory column in the table.

For example I want to see this:

```
| file1.csv | Last Write Access | .\Desktop\Folder1 |  
| file2.txt | Last Write Access | .\Desktop\Folder2 |
```

when the $Source is defined as `C:\users\User1`

Here is my current code:

```powershell
$Source = "C:\Users\User1"
$Months = "24"
$Size = 10MB
$OutSource = "C:\Export"
$LogName = "Export"
$Ext = "csv"

$Date = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-$Months)

Get-ChildItem -Path "$Source\*.*" -Recurse -Force | `
    Where-Object {$_.LastAccessTime -lt $Date -and $_.Length -gt $Size} | `
        Format-Table -AutoSize -Property Name, LastWriteTime, LastAccessTime, Directory | `
            Out-String -Width 4096 | `
                Out-File $OutSource\$LogName.$Ext
```

Answer (score 8):

There are 2 other solutions for this

As of Windows 10 / Windows server 2016 (Build 1607 or newer) you can use to remove

```
Set-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem' -Name 'LongPathsEnabled' -value 1
```

If you are using `PowerShell 5.1` or above you can use

```
get-childitem -LiteralPath
```

So in this case you would define `$Source = "\\?\C:\Users\User1"` and replace `Get-ChildItem -Path "$Source\*.*" -Recurse -Force`
with `Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath "$Source\*.*" -Recurse -Force`

Comment: Perhaps also worth noting if you're on an older version of Windows with an earlier PowerShell version, there are updates available for Win 7 to 8.1 / Server 2008 R2 to 2012 R2 to install WMF 5.1 which updates PS to 5.1. - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616 - thus allowing you to use the solution from @Drifter104

Comment: Please add an apostrophe before 'LongPathsEnabled', otherwise there is one apostrophe missing

Answer (score 0):

After an extensive search and trial and error, I have found a solution to my problem.

As there is no way to truncate the first part of the path, I have instead added a line of code to create a temporary network drive to do the truncating.

Code used:

```
New-PSDrive "X" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "$Source"
```

And changed the

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "$Source\*.*" -Recurse -Force | `
```

To

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "X:\*.*" -Recurse -Force | `
```

So my current output is somewhat what I was after:

```
| file1.csv | Last Write Access | X:\Desktop\Folder1 |
| file2.txt | Last Write Access | X:\Desktop\Folder2 |
```

Comment: New-PSDrive is the PowerShell way to do it - but `net use` will also do the trick.